# Accessing array within a hash within a hash (adding new values)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Thank you for the help in advance!
I'd like to add or push a value into my array which is currently within a person hash and task hash.

Look below at the add task section `task.merge!`

```
task = {
"person1" => { 
    :high => ["email", "phone","email2","talk","meeting"], 
    :mid => ["task1","task2"], 
    :low => ["task1","task2"] },

"person2" => { 
    :high => ["email", "phone","email2","talk","meeting"], 
    :mid => ["task1","task2"], 
    :low => ["task1","task2"] },

"person3" => { 
    :high => ["email", "phone","email2","talk","meeting"], 
    :mid => ["task1","task2"], 
    :low => ["task1","task2"] },
}

puts task["person1"][:high][0]

# create task
    #create new person hash within task hash
    #already have :high, :mid, & :low hash
# add task
    #add a task to the array within either high,mid, or low
    task.merge!("person1" => {:high => "#{new_task}")
# remove task
    #delete method
```

Comment: And your question is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task.merge! "person1" => {:high => "#{new_task}"}
```

You simply had an error there.  I removed the parenthesis to make it maybe a little more obvious.

Comment: A vote and accept is thanks enough, it is why we are here to help, regardless!